# what is the difference between the two below assignments?

Tags: c, output, variable-assignment

This is the source code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 5, *j, *k;
    j = &i;
    k = j;        // first assignment
    k = (int*)j;  // second assignment
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between the two assignments to the variable `k`?

Answer (score 2):

**In this case there is none.**

`j` is already an *integer pointer*, so no need to cast it. `(int*)` is redundant.

But in case the pointer types does not match by declaration, someone may need to explecitly cast it to appropriate pointer type.

Comment: what if I do k=(int)j; rather than k=(int*)j;

Comment: `j` is a pointer to an integer variable, converting it to `int` has little use. and again storing it to a pointer converts it back to a pointer type, so there is particularly no use of doing `k=(int)j`, and the compiler will show a warning probably.

Comment: @learner: On a 64bit machine, with `sizeof(int)` = `4` doing `k=(int)j` will loses have of `j`'s  information.

Comment: @learner in 64 bit machine, `sizeof(int) = 4` and `sizeof(int*) = 8`, so if you store `int*` in `int`, 4 byte will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

`j` is already an int-pointer, so the cast is redundant. Both statements will assign the same value to `k` (namely, the address of the variable `i`)

Comment: what if I do 
`k=(int)j;` rather than `k=(int*)j;`

Comment: @Vladp Not exactly compilation error.It should be warning of typecasting pointer to integer.

Comment: yes sorry about that, it's depends on the compiler, but it won't be more than a warning anyway.

Comment: Since `k` is a pointer you should not assign it integers. It works, but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Dayalrai Actually compiler would whine about trying to assign integer to pointer. Explicit casting of `j` to `(int)` is not a problem for compiler.

Comment: @user694733 Requesting you to try this at your end with strict warning level. There are two separate warning, one is for casting and another is for assignment.

Comment: @Dayalrai I did. Only one warning: *Error[Pe513]: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"* (IAR compiler). The point of explicit cast is to tell the compiler: "Shut up, I know what I am doing."

Answer (score 1):

In the second assignment you do an explicit cast to the type of `k` which happens to be the same as the type of `j`.
If they would have a different type but the types where convertable, the second assignment should still be valid, while the first one yields an error.

Comment: What's an *implicit cast*? There's no such thing. Casts are using the cast operator and thus are explicit if you will. Everything else is merely a *conversion*.

Comment: You're right I mixed implicit with explicit, will fix. Point is that you don't need the casting operator in all case, hence the casting is hidden to the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

**No Casting Required in case of similar data type:**

`k and j` is integer pointer  Here there is no need of explicit type casting during assignment of `k = (int*)j` address of `j` into `k`. Here casting is redundant.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 5, *j, *k;
    j = &i;
    k = j;        // first assignment
    k = (int*)j;  // second assignment
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 . In your example, `void *s; float *b; b = s; printf("%f",*b);` will work. It should be **Castin required when dereferencing `void` pointers**, like `void *s; float b; b = *(float*)s; printf("%f",b);` casting is must in this case, not in the 1st.